# How do I use a regular expression to select liquid tags within quotation marks, but not necessarily following/followed by quotation marks

Tags: regex, ruby, jekyll, liquid

I'd like to select all occurrences of the following liquid tags:

```
{%-

-%}
```

when they occur within quotation marks but not necessarily immediately following or followed by quotation marks.

Attempted several, think I am getting closer with:  `(?<=")({%-)(?=")`

Very new to regex - I appreciate your help.

Example of what I am attempting to do:

```
{%- assign foo = true -%}

<span class="{%- if foo == true -%} blue{%- else -%} red{%- endif -%}">item</span>
```

then use regex to replace {%- and -%} only if within/next to `"`:

```
{%- assign foo = true -%}   (no replacement)

<span class="{% if foo == true %} blue{% else %} red{% endif %}">item</span>  (replaced)
```

Thank you very much for your expertise and assistance.

Comment: Any regex with `.*` or `.*?` or `\G` is wrong because the start and end delimiter are identical here (`"`) and it is not possible to do this replacement without a callback. More, it looks like HTML, do not parse HTML with regex, parse with the DOM parser and use regex against plain text values.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - It can be done, provided that there aren't any escaped `"` symbols. If there's an example for which my regex breaks, I'd like to see it, so I can fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that maybe you might be trying to write an expression similar to:

```
(?=.*")-%|(?=.*")%-
```

and replace it with `%`.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fIAULy/1/)

`(?=.*")` will check for at least a `"` in the line, which you can change that.

Comment: Thank you very much Emma for your help! This worked for my particular case. I have much to learn and am excited to begin my regex journey. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Took a while, but here is a perfect regex for your problem:

Find:

```
((?<pad>\A[^"]*"[^"]*?|\G[^"{}]*|\G"[^"]*")(((?<start>\{%)-(?<content>[^"]*?)-(?<end>%\}))|(?<pad2>[^"{}%]*)))
```

Replace:

```
${pad}${pad2}${start}${content}${end}
```

Explanation:

This regex will search from the start of the string for a quote (`"`). Upon finding one, it will search for tags, and save them in groups (without the `-` symbols), and substitute them in. It will keep doing this until it finds another quote.

When it finds an ending quote, it will ignore everything until the next starting quote, upon which it starts the pattern again.

[Try it online!](https://regex101.com/r/S0XL06/2)

Comment: See the [most common scenario breaking the regex](https://regex101.com/r/ulrE2a/1). Do not try to fix it with regex, it makes no sense, one must use a DOM parser for such delimited text manipulation.